# How to analyze create react app build size and reduce it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bundle

I have been following this guide: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/analyzing-the-bundle-size/ and just about to run the `analyze` command to see how big my app is. is this the best way to check bundle/build size in React/JS?

also is there a way to not include certain files from the prod build? like tests? Does CRA handle this automatically?

Comment: tests, comments and other such misc things, get stripped out. if you aren't satisfied w/ CRA analyze, try out: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer. Webpack automatically will trim out whatever you don't reference in your codebase.

Comment: @dixitk13 does this mean I'll have to eject though?

Comment: let me know if the below helps. I've created the sample projected using CRA.

Answer (score 16):

As per the official Create React App documentation (https://create-react-app.dev/docs/analyzing-the-bundle-size/):

Below are the steps:

#### Step 1: add Source map explorer

`npm install --save source-map-explorer`

Alternatively, you may use yarn:

`yarn add source-map-explorer`

#### Step 2: Include npm script

```
"scripts": {
+    "analyze": "source-map-explorer 'build/static/js/*.js'",
     "start": "react-scripts start",
     "build": "react-scripts build",
     "test": "react-scripts test",
```

#### Step 3: Run the scripts to build the app

`npm run build`

#### Step 4: Run the scripts to analyze the build created in step3

`npm run analyze`

Now you should see a screen in your browser opened like this
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to eject. Try this:

1. install the analyser:[image]

```
➜  simple-react-router git:(master) ✗ npm install webpack-bundle-analyzer --save-dev
```

1. create a new file, I called mine: sample.js

```
➜  simple-react-router git:(master) ✗ cat sample.js 
process.env.NODE_ENV = "production"
var BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require("webpack-bundle-analyzer")
  .BundleAnalyzerPlugin

const webpackConfigProd = require("react-scripts/config/webpack.config.prod")

webpackConfigProd.plugins.push(
  new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
    analyzerMode: "static",
    reportFilename: "report.html",
  })
)

require("react-scripts/scripts/build")
```

2. Run with node

```
➜  simple-react-router git:(master) ✗ node sample.js                                
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm update caniuse-lite browserslist`
Creating an optimized production build...
Webpack Bundle Analyzer saved report to /Users/dixitk13/code/simple-react-router/build/report.html
Compiled successfully.

File sizes after gzip:

  54.49 KB  build/static/js/1.0ee1e308.chunk.js
  1.9 KB    build/static/js/main.73bea786.chunk.js
  763 B     build/static/js/runtime~main.229c360f.js
.
.
.
```

a new browser tab should open for you.

Comment: this is really helpful! but how for example can I get it to remove certain files from the build process?

Comment: could you define certain? also, you might need to eject but let's hear what you wanna remove first.

Comment: I want to remove anything relating to storybook from my apps main bundle..

Comment: You could use the exclude variable. `const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  mode: 'development',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: [
          './src/stories/'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
};`

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

- Install webpack-bundle-analyzer and config that in your webpack config.
- Try to use the webpack code splitting feature to reduce the file sizes at the first load time.